# RecursiveDirectoryIterator with RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator isn't filtering file names properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to recursively search for all files with the given name while ignoring certain sub-directories. I can't figure out why it is resulting in an empty array.

```
<?php

$filename    = 'phpunit.xml';
$ignoredDirs = ['/vagrant_web/vendor', '/vagrant_web/public'];

$directories = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/vagrant_web', \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$filter      = new \RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
    $directories,
    function ($current, $key, $iterator) use ($filename, $ignoredDirs) {
        $path = $current->getPathName();

        foreach ($ignoredDirs as $ignore) {
            if (strpos($path, $ignore) !== false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ($current->getFileName() != $filename) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
);

$files = [];
foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter) as $file) {
    $files[] = $file;
}

print_r($files);
```

If I echo out `$current->getPathName()` or `$current->getFileName()` I can see that the paths are being iterated over and there are files named phpunit.xml, but the resulting $files array is always empty.

If I remove the check on filename within the callback it works (I get all files from the expected paths)

```
$filename    = 'phpunit.xml';
$ignoredDirs = ['/vagrant_web/vendor', '/vagrant_web/public'];

$directories = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/vagrant_web', \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$filter      = new \RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
    $directories,
    function ($current, $key, $iterator) use ($filename, $ignoredDirs) {
        $path = $current->getPathName();

        foreach ($ignoredDirs as $ignore) {
            if (strpos($path, $ignore) !== false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

//        if ($current->getFileName() != $filename) {
//            return false;
//        }

        return true;
    }
);

$files = [];
foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter) as $file) {
    $files[] = $file;
}

print_r($files);
```

What is going on here? How can I search for a specific filename while ignoring certain directories?

Answer (score 0):

inlcude this at the top of your callback function:

```
if($iterator->hasChildren()) {
  return true;
}
```